# Casting UITextField text value to Boolean

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, ipad

I recognize that I have a string expression which I need to cast it to Boolean from UITextField text. Is there any easier way to cast to boolean straight from uitextfield which is only returning Yes or No?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using `UITextField`, use `UISwitch` to get a boolean value. According to Apple developer documentation, to get boolean values, you should use `UISwitch`.

Answer (score 5):

Check the documentation for [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

```
BOOL boolValue = [textField.text boolValue];
```

**Update**

It depends what is actually providing the input for the `UITextField` but I would say if it is user input then @amit's answer is better and you should change your design to use that.

My answer still stands as a good reminder that `NSString` has nice methods for returning primitive values such as `boolValue`, `intValue`, `floatValue`...etc

Answer (score 0):

```
BOOL boolValue = [textField.text isEqualToString:@"Yes"] ? YES : NO;
```

Comment: With this, `@"YES"`, `@"yes"`, `@"Y"`, `@"1"`, etc. → `NO`.

Comment: I believe the original poster said the value could be only YES or NO.  But if not,  there's also @"Yes", @"y", @"t", @"T", @"TRUE", @"True"

Comment: @OwenHartnett `NSString`'s `boolValue` method deals with all of these

Comment: Actually I found a way to convert that type as:

    [parameters setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:news] forKey:@"news"];

This works fine for my situation.

Thanks everyone, as I don't consider the above solution as wrong either.

Comment: @kforkarim, please close the question.

Comment: @Paul.s yes, you are correct, it is a nice method.  It should be noted that it will also return YES if the string includes the digits 1-9.